# How to set the header of a response in production mode in play 2

Tags: playframework-2.0

I made a website which lets users upload images and serves them back. To lower the load i've tried to use client side caching like so:

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
response().setHeader(CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=3600");
response().setHeader(ETAG, image);
return ok(data);
```

This works fine in development mode (play run) but when i run the site in production mode the headers are gone and nothing is cached.

Thanks